# variable getting output before it's value is updated by a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that outputs the initialized value of my variable before it is updated by  an $.ajax() callback.  It seems that the 'get' is performed after the variable is logged despite how the code is written. How can I correct this? Thanks for any suggestions.

```
var statusUpdate = {
    queries : [],
    numQueries : 0,
    getNumQueries : function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '40985839503175/planXML.txt',
            cache: false,
            error: function()
            { 

            },
            success: function(data){
                statusUpdate.queries = $(data).find('query');
                statusUpdate.numQueries = statusUpdate.queries.length;
                //console.log(statusUpdate.numQueries);

            }

        });

        }  // end getNumQueries

};


statusUpdate.getNumQueries();
console.log(statusUpdate.numQueries)
```

Comment: It's a matter of ajax being Asyncronous JAvascript. the success function is not called before getNumQueries complete and continues at the next line. This question has also been asked a gazillion times here on SO so your not the first :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var statusUpdate = {
    queries : [],
    numQueries : 0,
    getNumQueries : function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '40985839503175/planXML.txt',
            cache: false,
            error: function()
            { 

            },
            success: function(data){
                statusUpdate.queries = $(data).find('query');
                statusUpdate.numQueries = statusUpdate.queries.length;
                console.log(statusUpdate.numQueries);

            }

        });

        }  // end getNumQueries

};
```

Uncomment the logger in the success callback. Otherwise the log may run before the ajax call gets a chance to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are asynchronous. I'm guessing that you are seeing `0` in your console?

Put the `console.log` inside the success function. But I'd recommend passing a callback or returning the promise object (it will require you to restructure your JavaScript).

```
var statusUpdate = {
    queries : [],
    numQueries : 0,
    getNumQueries : function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '40985839503175/planXML.txt',
            cache: false,
            error: function()
            {

            },
            success: function(data){
                statusUpdate.queries = $(data).find('query');
                statusUpdate.numQueries = statusUpdate.queries.length;

                console.log(statusUpdate.numQueries)
            }

        });

        }  // end getNumQueries

};


statusUpdate.getNumQueries();
```

**UPDATE**: Here's what I meant by using a promise. For more info, see [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) and the [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
var statusUpdate = {
    queries : [],
    numQueries : 0,
    getNumQueries : function(){
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: '40985839503175/planXML.txt',
            cache: false
        }).done(function(data){
                statusUpdate.queries = $(data).find('query');
                statusUpdate.numQueries = statusUpdate.queries.length;

                deferred.resolve();
        ).fail(function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });

        return deferred.promise();
    }  // end getNumQueries

};


statusUpdate.getNumQueries().done(function () {
    console.log(statusUpdate.numQueries)
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, when I log it from inside the success function I get the right value, and zero otherwise.  The problem is I want to use the updated value from the success function to do something else so I need it after it has been updated.

Comment: The re-structured code above that uses the jQuery Deferred object should help you with that. Deferred objects are fun and very useful once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I added complete before seeing your code. It looks like your code will give me what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I can't make it work as envisioned. I added a complete function but it seems like kind of a workaround. Is this a reasonable practice? Thanks.